# jQuery .done() .fail()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What we want here is to manipulate the `createSite` function expected return which is `{ac:failed}` so when it failed `.fail(failOption)` will be execute else `sendMail` / `.done(sendMail)` function will execute and still holding the data from `createSite` function which is the `{bar1:"foo1",bar2:"foo2",bar3:"foo3"}`

```
var cSite = createSite(); //expected return if failed is {ac:"failed"} else success expected return will be {bar1:"foo1",bar2:"foo2",bar3:"foo3"}


var cSite = createSite();
cSite.done(sendMail).fail(failOption).always(alwaysOption);

function createSite() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'something.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: "template_id=" + template_id + "&original_url=" + original_url + "&email=" + email + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&last_name=" + last_name
    }); //ajax
} //createSite
```

Comment: Take a look at jQuery's deferred object: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `fail` part of the `ajax` promise is triggered on http statuses other than the 200 range I imagine, like `400: bad request` or `500: internal server error`.

If you cannot pass a fail status from `something.php`, there are two options. For jQuery 1 and 2:

```
function createSite() {
    var promise = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'something.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: "template_id=" + template_id + "&original_url=" + original_url + "&email=" + email + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&last_name=" + last_name
    }).then(function(data) {
        if(data.ac === 'failed') {
            promise.reject(failed)
        } else {
            promise.resolve(data);
        }
    })

    return promise;
}
```

In newer versions of jQuery (3+), you can also throw an error to trigger a `fail`:

```
function createSite() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'something.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: "template_id=" + template_id + "&original_url=" + original_url + "&email=" + email + "&first_name=" + first_name + "&last_name=" + last_name
    }).then(function(data) {
        if(data.ac === 'failed') {
            throw data
        } else {
            return data
        }
    });
}
```

Please note that this is completely untested. The documentation for `deferred` is [here](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/).

Comment: I know, but it doesn't fail on a success status, which is what OP is asking

Comment: Well you don't need a promise for that, you can just call a fail function.

Comment: You can have a fail function outside of the ajax call and call it in the same place you currently call the reject function. There is no need for another promise.

Comment: My first suggestion was to return a fail status from the server. Feel free to write a better answer.

Comment: The core of your answer is correct. The use of promises is irrelevant.

Comment: Ahh ok. Yeah I suppose that is cleaner

Comment: It may well depend on the version of jQuery though :p

Comment: Haha! Why don't I include both for completeness sake

Comment: FYI: the cleaner Promise/A+ compliant code works in jQuery 3.x - not in jQuery 1.x or 2.x

Comment: Thanks for looking it up... Amended the answer. Better this way?

Comment: I've used the newer version code but it didn't trigger the fail.. which is my .fail(sendMail)

Comment: are you using jquery 3.x?

Comment: yap 3.1.0 to be exact

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134036/discussion-between-camdev-and-jorg).